# Set Windows XP power button action to "Do nothing" with script or registry setting

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, power-options

How do I set the "When I press the power button on my computer:" option in Windows XP to "Do nothing" with a registry key or script?

I found [this example](http://ask.metafilter.com/189659/Why-does-powercfg-not-do-what-I-want-in-Windows-7) in searching, however it is supposed to be for the sleep button, and it doesn't seem to work.

I found these keys, but I have no idea what the correct value should be since it is REG_BINARY

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Power\AcPolicy
HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Power\DcPolicy
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power\AcPolicy
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power\DcPolicy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I could not figure out the appropriate registry key values, I ended up just writing a script to automate the dialog. And since I was using AutoIT for other things, that's what I used. Hope this can help someone else.

```
#include <GuiTab.au3>
; Start the System control panel
Run("rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL powercfg.cpl,,3")

$title = "Power Options Properties"
$text = ""
WinWait( $title, $text)
If Not WinActive( $title, $text) Then WinActivate( $title, $text)
WinWaitActive( $title, $text)

;select the 'Advanced' tab
$hTab = ControlGetHandle( $title, $text, "[CLASS:SysTabControl32; INSTANCE:1]")
_GUICtrlTab_ClickTab($hTab, 1)
Sleep(10)

;set the combobox to 'Do nothing'
ControlCommand( $title, $text, "[CLASS:ComboBox; INSTANCE:2]", "SelectString", "Do nothing")
Sleep(10)

;click OK
ControlClick( $title, $text, "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:6]")
```

The script just opens the power options dialog, selects the advanced tab, sets the combo to 'Do nothing', and presses OK.

Answer (score 2):

> Do not know if you are still looking for a solution. I needed something to change the Power Button setting from the default "Shutdown" to "Do nothing", so I wrote this vbscript.

```
'***************************************************************************************
' File:             pwrDoNothing.vbs
' Author:           Joe Rawlins
' Purpose:          Set system Power Button to 'Do nothing'
'                   
'
' Notes:            Requires button to be held for 5 seconds to initiate shutdown
'                   
'                   
'                   
'
' Last Modified:    06/25/2010  jtr Initial creation
'                   
'***************************************************************************************
Option Explicit

Dim objShell, WshShell

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objShell.ControlPanelItem("powercfg.cpl")

WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "+{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "{RIGHT}"
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB 2}"
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "{UP 2}"
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

[Source of script](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/f6cb0826-e36c-464c-89a6-a0132b70d1d8)

Comment: Thanks @Luke, I tried that but had no luck, mostly because I have no clue about HTML

Comment: @Luke: that looks pretty good, and would probably work, I'll give it a try if I can't find the correct registry key value.

Comment: If someone can find the registry value it changes, that would make it work a lot smoother, especially on a wider range of hardware

Comment: Install Process monitor on a PC and change the setting in the gui, then search the PM snapsot for the registry calls....http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645